# Оптимизировать вывод ToolTip в компонентах PrimeNG

Tags: angular2

Делаю небольшой проект на Angular 4 + PrimeNG. В шаблоне одного из компонентов используем компонент ToolTip. Есть необходимость определять, помещается ли текст в поле ввода и в зависимости от этого выводить подсказку или нет. Привожу фрагмент шаблона компонента

```
<input type="text" pInputText #gng pTooltip="{{getTip(gngName)}}"
       tooltipPosition="top" [(ngModel)]="gngGngName" />
```

Метод, выводящий подсказку

```
 getTip(param : string): string {
    return param;
 }
```

Любые варианты с методом length не подходят, так как использована адаптивная верстка (через Grid CSS).

Кто нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой, какие есть способы решения?