# Реализовать условный вывод подсказки ToolTip в элементе InputText

Tags: angular2, primefaces

Делаем небольшой проект на Angular 4 + PrimeNG. Возникла задача использования подсказки в элементах ввода InputText. Необходимо определить длину строки в InputText для принятия решения - выводить подсказку или нет. Для подсказки используется стандартный компонент PrimeNG ToolTip. Любые варианты с методом length не подходят, так как использована адаптивная верстка (через Grid CSS).  Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной задачей и как выходили из ситуации?

Comment: зачем нужно дублировать вопросы? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/760832/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-tooltip-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85-primeng